# How can I format the items of file to comply with the items in another file in python?

Tags: python, list

I have two files containing records of this form 'Date',"points','Name', but there are differences between the two files regarding the name,for example Bob in one file and Bobb in another.I am trying to have Bob in all the files.Any tips ?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could read in each file using the "csv" module, then write a conversion dictionary {'Bobb':'Bob',...} and run through the rows checking to see if the name is in the dict.